# What does SUMPRODUCT do in the following formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I am sorry for a noob question, but I am just learning.

[Here there is a tutorial](https://trumpexcel.com/find-last-occurrence/) to find Last Occurrence of a value. `SUMPRODUCT` is used for arrays, but `MAX` in the formula below will return only one max value from an array:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$14,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($A$2:$A$14)*($D$3=$A$2:$A$14))-1))
```

and the tutorial's explanation is that

> SUMPRODUCT is used to ensure that you don’t have to use Control + Shift + Enter, as SUMPRODUCT can handle array formulas.

I have no idea what `Control + Shift + Enter` does and what `array formulas` is it talking about. I have even removed `SUMPRODUCT` from the formula and it works. Would you please explain what the cited explanation means and why do we need `SUMPRODUCT` to use on a single number?

Answer (score 0):

> MAX in the formula below will return only one max value from an array:

You're right but arrays need to be enabled in order to perform the following operation...

> ROW($A$2:$A$14)*($D$3=$A$2:$A$14)

...otherwise it will just evaluate the first multiplication `ROW(A2)*(D3=A2)`

Said that, I don't see the purpose of `SUMPRODUCT()` here as `INDEX()` already enables arrays.